Ida Pro: Get original type of typedef from local types with the IDA C++ API
I've been poking around with the IDA C++ SDK and I'm writing something to dump all local types into a json file. I have it all working but typedefs. Example typedef int BOOL
I'm trying to get the original type of the typedef all methods I have tried so far only give me BOOL for the typedef name and the original type. I've tried the get_final_type_name function, get_realtype(true) which caused crashes and some others which gave the same result as get_final_type_name. Is there an easy way to do this?

In Python, at least, you'll need to use get_numbered_type or get_named_type. That'll get you the fields that you can use with tinfo_t.deserialize. If you already have the "typeref" that you want as a tinfo_t, you'll need to distinguish whether it's a named-type or ordinal-type and then use get_type_name or get_ordinal (respectively). With that, you can then get_numbered_type or get_named_type. It's also probably worth noting that you can use replace_ordinal_typerefs to replace ordinals in your type with a named type (prolly affecting lookup performance).
